# How to add a forward circular icon on the ProgressIndicator of the video_player in Flutter

Tags: flutter, video-player

I have implemented a Video Player in flutter using the official `video_player` plugin.

This is my code for ProgressIndicator :

```
VideoProgressIndicator(
                              _videoPlayerController,
                              allowScrubbing: true,
                              colors: const VideoProgressColors(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                // bufferedColor: Colors.yellow,
                                playedColor: Color(0xff18BAE8),
                              ),
                            ),
```

But the progress indicator doesn't have a lead circular shape that I want something like this :

[image: ProgressIndicator with a lead circular shape]

The default Progress Indicator is just a straight line and doesn't have any circular shape as in this picture. How can I create one?

Comment: hi @Sahil Singh have u found anything

Comment: I am using better_player now. Here : https://pub.dev/packages/better_player It works mostly for what I want.

Comment: Hi, @SahilSingh did you find anything on it?